# PHP 7 - How to access variable in another PHP tag

Tags: php, sql, variables, version, global

I've recently switched my PHP version from 5.4 to 7.1.
The problem occurs when I try to connect to a database using a variable that is declared at the beginning of the file. The code is structured like this :

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('...','...','...','...');
?>
--SOME HTML--
<?php
$sql = "SOME SQL";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Why do I need to structure my code using this schema? I need to access the database from multiple parts of the script, so I opted for a single connection variable instead of declaring it every time I need to connect to my database.
When I run the script, it gives me this error :

> Undefined variable : conn in (myfile.phpp).

Is this a PHP version problem? If yes, how do I create a single variable to access in the entire script?
Thanks!

Comment: You should have access to the $conn variable from any part of the script.
That's weird.!

Comment: This is not php version problem. This is your code problem. Code you show us __will work fine__. But your real code is obviously differs from what you show us.

Comment: @u_mulder This has always worked for me.

Comment: And now it __doesn't__. So this means that code in which it works and your current code __differs__.

Comment: Are you trying to access it inside a function within the second block?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes I'm trying to access it in a function called when a form is submitted.

Comment: Then is `$conn` passed as an argument to that function? [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @TomUdding Thanks. This worked.